# Issue with variadic template template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-templates

Consider the following example:

```
template< class A, int B, class C>
struct Obj {
A a_obj;
static constexpr int b_value = B;
C c_obj;

};

template< template<class... > class ... Templates >
struct Foo;


template<>
struct Foo<Obj> {

Obj<void*, 5, float> obj;
};


int main() {
Foo<Obj> foo;

};
```

This is failing on me (g++ 7.2, with `-std=c++17` with the following errors:

```
templ.cpp:16:15: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class ...> class ... Templates> struct Foo’
   16 | struct Foo<Obj> {
      |               ^
templ.cpp:16:15: note:   expected a template of type ‘template<class ...> class ... Templates’, got ‘template<class A, int B, class C> struct Obj’
templ.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
templ.cpp:23:8: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class ...> class ... Templates> struct Foo’
   23 | Foo<Obj> foo;
      |        ^
templ.cpp:23:8: note:   expected a template of type ‘template<class ...> class ... Templates’, got ‘template<class A, int B, class C> struct Obj’
```

It seems that it is not getting matched, although it doesn't look like it thinks the `template<class ...> class ... Templates` is a syntax error, hence the parameter-parameter pack is parsing

Is this type of declaration (with some types, a constant value, then more types, or perhaps constant values at the end) unmatchable with variadic template template pack syntax? or perhaps I'm not using the syntax right

### Edit

I modified the version to avoid non-types in declarations, but the problem persists:

```
template< template <class, class> class B, class A, class C>
struct Obj {
A a_obj;
//static constexpr int b_value = B;
B< C, A > b_obj;
C c_obj;

};

template< template<typename... > typename ... Templates >
struct Foo;

template<class A, class V>
struct Bar {
A a_obj;
//static constexpr int value = V;
V obj;
};

template<>
struct Foo<Obj> {

Obj<Bar, void*, float> obj;
};


int main() {
Foo<Obj> foo;

};
```

So it seems that is not that just non-types and types cannot be matches on a variadic pack, but any mixture of types and templates

I also tried adding an additional variadic pack:

```
template< template<typename... > typename ... Templates, class ... Types >
struct Foo;
```

But then I get:

```
error: parameter pack ‘template<class ...> class ... Templates’ must be at the end of the template parameter list
   12 | template< template<typename... > typename ... Templates, class ... Types >
```

Comment: You can't match a mix of types and non-types with a variadic pack. You'd need something like `template< template<class,int,class > class ... Templates >`.

Comment: A class template can't have two parameter packs either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int B` is a non-type template parameter. You have to declare `Templates` as `template<class, auto, class> class` if you want it to work with that particular class template, or redefine `Obj` to take a [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) to pass a value encapsulated in a type:

```cpp
template<class A, class B, class C>
struct Obj {
    A a_obj;
    static constexpr int b_value = B::value;
    C c_obj;
};

template<template<class...> class... Templates>
struct Foo;

template<>
struct Foo<Obj> {
    Obj<void*, std::integral_constant<int, 5>, float> obj;
};

int main() {
    Foo<Obj> foo;
}
```

[Try it on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/fh1vvqW7o).

Comment: interesting. Indeed it seems that mixing non-types with types breaks any sort of variadic pack declaration, regardless if it contains template template parameters or not

Comment: @lurscher there is an [open proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1985r0.pdf) to address scenarios like this

Comment: Patrick, I tried modifying the example by removing all mention of non-types, just mixing types and templates in the variadic pack, and I got essentially the same error

Comment: @lurscher again, `template <class, class> class B` is not a type, it's a templated type. `class` does not apply.